# How to find all the zero cells in a python panda dataframe and replace them?

Tags: python, pandas

My data is like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [5,0,0, 6, 0, 0, 0 , 12]})
```

I want to count the zeros above the 6 and replace them with `(6/count+1)=(6/3)=2` (I will also replace the original 6)
I also want to do a similar thing with the zeros above the 12.
So, `(12/count)=(12/3)=4`
So the final result will be:

```
[5,2,2, 2, 3, 3, 3 , 3]
```

I am not sure how to start. Are there any functions that do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `mean` and custom groups created with test not equal `0`, swap order, cumulative sum and swap order to original:

```
g = df['a'].ne(0).iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1]
df['b'] = df.groupby(g)['a'].transform('mean')
print (df)
    a  b
0   5  5
1   0  2
2   0  2
3   6  2
4   0  3
5   0  3
6   0  3
7  12  3
```